# Find four coordinates of the rectangle after the rotation and translation

Tags: javascript, math, transformation, css-transforms

I need to adapt the algorithm (or find the formula) to work in all three dimensions to find the new four coordinates. In the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/cLpkqs1j/2/) i've obtained the new width and height of a transformed (rotate and perspective), but i don't know how to extract the angle and the new coordinates.

```
var x = Math.cos(angle) * origy;
var z = Math.sin(angle) * origy;
return x * p / (p + z);
```

Comment: Regarding my previous experience, the easiest way is managing  rotation, scale and translation by a 3d transformation matrix then multiplying your reference points by your result matrix.

Comment: these are linear transformations: just apply the matrix multiplications for this Rotate/Translation to individual coordinates and done.

Comment: The equations you posted are wrong.  You need to learn about linear algebra and matrix transformations.  Try this: http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node99.html